# li slideDown works, but when slideUp it just pops up without sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been having some problems with my code for making a `<li>` slideDown when I click a button.
I tried to make a jsFiddle but for some reason the CSS wasn't showing. But [here](http://jsfiddle.net/26gPJ/2/) it is.

I have a website with a center filled with nothing. Both sides have navigation bars, and right now it's only the left one that has anything in it. It has a `<div>` with a `<ul>` in it, and to the very right of each `<li>` there is a little expand button, and when that is clicked (only the one besides "What is this?"), outside of "What is this" then a small hidden text do `slideDown(500)` and the expand img changes to a contract img. And if the contract img is clicked then it's supposed to do `slideUp(500)` but for some reason it just pops right back to being hidden without doing the `slideUp(500)`.

Comment: Your JSFiddle appears to have no output for me?

Comment: @Michael that's because of the `margin-top: -155px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs a little work but I updated your example to fix your major problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#whatExpand").click(function () {
        $("#whatExpand").hide();
        $("#whatContract").show();
        $("#whatRolldown").slideDown(500);
        //$("#whatRolldown").css("display, inline");
    });

    $("#whatContract").click(function () {
        $("#whatContract").hide();
        $("#whatExpand").show();
        $("#whatRolldown").slideUp(500);
        //$("#whatRolldown").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/26gPJ/5/

JQuery handles all the fancy stuff so don't worry about setting the display value for the content that is being hidden.

Comment: Thanks alot. I didn't know that jQuery does all the diplay value etc, and I din't know the .hide() and .show() so thanks for teaching me something new and helping me with my problem! :D

Answer (score 0):

jQuery animations are asynchronous. When you call `.slideUp()`, it fires off a timer that begins stepping through the animation, and returns control immediately (so that the browser doesn't lock up until the animation completes - because JavaScript is single threaded). So if you want something to happen after the animation completes, you pass that function (which is called a callback) as the second argument to `.slideUp()`. Example:

```
$("#whatRolldown").slideUp(500, function() { $(this).css("display", "none"); })
```

});

The reason you don't notice it on `slideDown()` is that `slideDown()` already sets the CSS `display` of the element to something other than `none` in order to ensure that the element is shown during the animation. So your `.css("display", "inline")` really isn't doing anything in this case.

Also, you're not seeing the output of your fiddle because you have `margin-top:-155px` on the `.bar` element.